# Why does this SSL certificate seem to be rejected by Kindle Fire?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

The SSL certificate for the domain `cf.geekdo-static.com` seems to pass all the online test for compatibility, gets an A rating from https://www.ssllabs.com, etc. But users on Kindle Fires, (and I've verified this on browserstack) can't load resources from this domain. Are we missing something in the SSL certificate? We don't have many users on Kindle fire, but if it is an easy fix, we'd like to fix our certificate.

Comment: Dang, yeah, typo in the question. Fixed now. FYI, this serves static content for another domain.

Comment: Please answer and accept your own question. It makes answers more obvious. Good that TLS is working.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't clear, @JohnMahowald. TLS is still broken for kindle devices for that domain. I fixed the typo in the question, but the problem described in the question remains an issue.